# How do I set VirtualBox VM options using docker-machine?

Tags: docker, boot2docker, docker-machine

Using `boot2docker` it is easy to set some VirtualBox VM options while initializing the VM like:

```
boot2docker --disksize=50000 --memory=4096 ...
```

Since the new *state of the art* is to create those VMs using `docker-machine` my question is: How can I pass those options to `docker-machine` while creating a new one with:

```
docker-machine create -d virtualbox test
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you run `docker-machine create --help` you can see the options that you can pass when creating the VM. In the case of the VirtualBox driver, this includes:

```
--virtualbox-cpu-count "1"          number of CPUs for the machine (-1 to use the number of CPUs available) [$VIRTUALBOX_CPU_COUNT]
--virtualbox-disk-size "20000"      Size of disk for host in MB [$VIRTUALBOX_DISK_SIZE]
--virtualbox-hostonly-cidr "192.168.99.1/24"    Specify the Host Only CIDR [$VIRTUALBOX_HOSTONLY_CIDR]
--virtualbox-memory "1024"          Size of memory for host in MB [$VIRTUALBOX_MEMORY_SIZE]
```